# How to use a proxy to access wcf service in .net core

Tags: wcf, proxy, .net-core

I'm add a wcf service in my code(.net core 2.1), but I cann't access this service directly, I need to use a proxy to do this , I don't know how to set proxy in my code. 
when i add a wcf service, vs generate a json file like this:

```js
{
  "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  "Version": "15.0.20628.921",
  "GettingStartedDocument": {
    "Uri": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=858517"
  },
  "ExtendedData": {
    "Uri": "http://xxxxx/eisp-zk/ws/zkiService?wsdl",
    "Namespace": "EispService",
    "SelectedAccessLevelForGeneratedClass": "Public",
    "GenerateMessageContract": false,
    "ReuseTypesinReferencedAssemblies": true,
    "ReuseTypesinAllReferencedAssemblies": true,
    "CollectionTypeReference": {
      "Item1": "System.Array",
      "Item2": "System.Runtime.dll"
    },
    "DictionaryCollectionTypeReference": {
      "Item1": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2",
      "Item2": "System.Collections.dll"
    },
    "CheckedReferencedAssemblies": [],
    "InstanceId": null,
    "Name": "EispService",
    "Metadata": {}
  }
}
```

I want to know how to set a proxy. anyone can help me？

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your issue, please see my updated reply.

Answer (score -2):

Connectedservice.json contains endpoint information and configuration information for the service to be accessed. 
You should use the automatically generated proxy class to access the service through this proxy class.

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
var result = client.SayHelloAsync();
Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
```

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide
Here are the examples of invocation in the netframework project.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.
**Updated.**
Proxy settings usually is completed in the binding settings.

```
        <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService"  proxyAddress="http://abcd"/>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

In the Core-based project, we usually call the service by means of `Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider`, the binding configuration is generated in the `Reference.cs`.
[image]
Related link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.proxyaddress?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.0#System_ServiceModel_BasicHttpBinding_ProxyAddress

Comment: He need a solution for .net core, not .net framework...